# simple_form custom input with custom wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to make a custom input for currency in my app. I had those bootstrap wrappers and etc (I think it comes with simple_form or with bootstrap gem...), so, I could do something like:

```
<%= f.input :cost, wrapper => :append do %>
      <%= content_tag :span, "$", class: "add-on" %>
      <%= f.number_field :cost %>
<% end %>
```

And it works just as expected. The thing is: I need this same thing in a lot of places, and I don't want to copy/paste it all around.

So, I decided to create a custom input.

Until now, I got the following code:

```
class CurrencyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base

  def input
    input_html_classes.unshift("string currency")
    input_html_options[:type] ||= input_type if html5?

    @builder.input attribute_name, :wrapper => :append do |b|
      # content_tag(:span, "$", class: "add-on")
      b.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
    end
  end
end
```

But I got some errors. Looks like the `b` doesn't came as expected, so, it just don't work.

Is it really possible to do this? I could't find any example and can't make it work by myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this should work:

https://gist.github.com/rafaelfranca/5158873

Comment: it works! But I really want to do this wrapper thing in my custom input, so I don't have to pass the wrapper option when I use the currency input. Is it possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use the wrapper_mappings option. See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb#L123

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That block variable is not existent, your input method have to be like this:

```
class CurrencyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base

  def input
    input_html_classes.unshift("string currency")
    input_html_options[:type] ||= input_type if html5?

    template.content_tag(:span, "$", class: "add-on") +
      @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

Now you can register a default wrapper to this custom input in you Simple Form initializer:

```
config.wrapper_mappings = { :currency => :append }
```

An you can use like this:

```
<%= f.input :cost, :as => :currency %>
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thank you very much Rafael, I didn't knew about the wrapper setup by field type. Cheers!