# Simple_form custom input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form, select2-rails

I have this line of code:

```
= f.input :goal, as: :select, input_html: {class: "select2"}, wrapper_html: {class: "form-fields"}
```

which I would like to turn to

```
= f.input :goal, as: :select2
```

using a custom input in simple_form. How do I achieve this? So far, I have:

```
class Select2Input < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    input_html_options[:class]<< 'select2'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

These may be of some help, though I am not very familiar with simple form.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-inputs-examples

[simple_form custom input with custom wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401199/simple-form-custom-input-with-custom-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you half-way there:

```
class Select2Input < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
end
```

and

```
<%= f.input :email, as: :select2, wrapper_html:{class: "form-fields"} %>
```

You may have to create a custom wrapper for the select2 input in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` to be able to use it in the way you really want.